# Replacing array string values which contains multiple special characters in php

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to replace array string values which contains multiple special characters to normal one.

## Tried Code (array values):

```
$data['ENV_TEST'] = "rambo";
$data['ENV_DEV'] = "Project Bribara<"${ENV_TEST}"@gmail.com>"

echo str_replace("${ENV_TEST}", $data['ENV_DEV'], $data['ENV_DEV']);
```

also tried

```
echo str_replace("\"${ENV_TEST}\"", $data['ENV_DEV'], $data['ENV_DEV']);
```

## Expected:

```
"Project Bribara<rambo@gmail.com>"
```

## Actual:

```
"Project Bribara<"${ENV_TEST}"@gmail.com>"
```

How can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should on [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) sometime. The important part about double quoted strings for your question is that you need to put a backslash before every $ and every " inside your string. Your code will then look like this:

```
$data['ENV_TEST'] = "rambo";
$data['ENV_DEV'] = "Project Bribara<\"\${ENV_TEST}\"@gmail.com>";

echo str_replace("\${ENV_TEST}", $data['ENV_TEST'], $data['ENV_DEV']);
//also tried
echo "\n\n";
echo str_replace("\"\${ENV_TEST}\"", $data['ENV_TEST'], $data['ENV_DEV']);
```

If you use single quoted strings you don't need to escape $ (see the manual), and instead of \", you would need to escape single quotes (but there aren't any in your example).

```
$data['ENV_TEST'] = "rambo";
$data['ENV_DEV'] = 'Project Bribara<"${ENV_TEST}"@gmail.com>';

echo str_replace("\${ENV_TEST}", $data['ENV_TEST'], $data['ENV_DEV']);
//also tried
echo "\n\n";
echo str_replace('"${ENV_TEST}"', $data['ENV_TEST'], $data['ENV_DEV']);
```

I also fixed a missing semicolon and replaced DEV with TEST in one place.

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation in PHP is done through the `.` operator. Your code would be:

```
$data['ENV_DEV'] = "Project Bribara<".$data['ENV_TEST']."@gmail.com>"
```